# How to resolve this query sql this?

Tags: sql

I have a query sql like this

```
select fname, idcard, left(idcard,3) as kodecard
from tcard
where kodecard = '200'
```

How to resolve my query? 
I just have 2 column (fname, and idcard) and I want to filter with the first three digits in idcard column.

Could you give me a solution?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Some product specifics there...)

Comment: Is kodecard a character type column? Or, why do you compare with a string literal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use your `LEFT` function in condition

```
select fname, idcard from tcard where left(idcard,3) = '200'
```

You may use `LIKE` as well.

```
select fname, idcard from tcard where idcard LIKE '200%'
```

This solution is better since it allows the query processor to use an index (if it is available).